# How to Override the get method of Tree Map in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a treemap. Its key and value is a bean of student which has two fields: `regno`, `name`.

If I have only reg no of any student, then how can I override the get method of tree map to fetch the value that is bean of that student?

Comment: Its key **and** value are `Student`?  As in, you have a `Map<Student, Student>`?  This is possible but probably not what you mean.

Comment: Why do you need to override `get`?  What is the definition of your `TreeMap`?  Is it currently `TreeMap<Student, Student>`?

Comment: Yes i have this type of configuration. And i have a regno... for which i have to fetch the complete bean of student

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to override anything in `TreeMap`; you just need to change how you use it.  Have the regno be the key and the student be the value, i.e. `TreeMap<Integer, Student>`, assuming `regno` is an integer.  Then you can call `get` with just the regno and retrieve the student.

Comment: I just put this as a example..... But in real i need to override this get method.